# copy style from bootstrap 5 button to label

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

For reasons I need my buttons to be `<labels class="btn">` and not regular `<button>`:

```
<label for="fileinput" class="custom-file-upload btn btn-primary"><i class="someicon"></i></label><input ...>
```

But this way the buttons do not get this nice shadow around them when clicking on them. Is there something else I have to add so it inherits the buttons CSS? Or do I have to create a css class and add all those effects by hand?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

.btn:focus {box-shadow:  0 0 3px 1px blue; outline: none;}

Answer (score 0):

When you `clicked` or `focused` on this `button`, you have this shadow... you can delete this shadow and outline like this:

```
.btn:focus {box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px blue; outline: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn
{
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 3px skyblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<label for="fileinput" class="custom-file-upload btn btn-primary">Primary</label>
```